# Reduce scope of VBA to single document?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following subroutine that works like I want when I only have this particular Excel file open

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Z11").Value > 0 Then
        Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("tileOverdueTasks").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(185, 0, 0)
    Else
        Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("tileOverdueTasks").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 185, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is, if I open another document while this one is open, I get the following error:

[image]

Debugging reveals where the issue is.

[image]

I'm new to VBA, but I tried adding `ActiveSheet` before all the Sheets references and that did not alleviate the error.  How can I make sure this only runs on the "Dashboard" Sheet in the document the script is located in?

Comment: This is bacause if you write just ```Sheets``` it is the same as ```ActiveWorkbook.Sheets```. So you would need to add the workbook qualifier something like ```Workbooks("MyBook").Sheets(...)```.

Comment: Use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")`

Comment: @dee: Your answer worked perfectly.  Please post as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is bacause if you write just `Sheets` it is the same as `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets`. So you would need to add the workbook qualifier something like `Workbooks("MyBook").Sheets("SheetName")`.

Or you could use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")`. Then the sheets collection of the workbook where the VBA code is running will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Change the code to the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Z11").Value > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("tileOverdueTasks").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(185, 0, 0)
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("tileOverdueTasks").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 185, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

By referencing the workbook with "ThisWorkbook", the code will only check in the workbook which the code resides in.